# How to collate an array of JSON objects by a property into a struct containing vectors of each object's properties?

Tags: json, vector, struct, rust, serde

I am receiving a stream of sensor data which I need to aggregate and perform basic statistics on (average, max, min, etc.). There are multiple values but the sensor data can be inconsistent and some of the values can be missing.

From reading the book, it seems like `Option` should be used when the values of `luminosity` or `color` are missing but I am confused about this.

This is an example of my sensor data:

```
[
    {
        "sensor": "left",
        "luminosity": "50",
        "color": "(255,0,0)"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "left",
        "color": "#0f0"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "right",
        "luminosity": "20"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "right",
        "luminosity": "40",
        "color": "(255,0,0)"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "left",
        "luminosity": "30"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "top",
        "luminosity": "10"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "right",
        "color": "(0,0,0)"
    }
]
```

Each sensor's data will be stored in an instance of the following struct:

```
struct Data {
    pub luminosity: Vec<String>,
    pub color: Vec<String>,
}
```

I want to iterate over the above JSON object, match the sensor to the correct struct instance ("right" sensors to the "right" sensor struct) and push the contents of each JSON observation onto the vectors (inside each struct instance).

Missing values need to be recorded so that for each "observation" there is one push action for every vector in the struct for the corresponding sensor's struct instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158788/discussion-between-greg-and-shepmaster).

Comment: This was [cross-posted to the user's forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-insert-the-contents-of-a-json-object-into-a-struct-containing-vectors/13830?u=shepmaster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work. It uses [Serde](https://serde.rs/) to read each JSON array element into a helper struct with a required sensor name `String`, and `Option<String>` data for each value of the sensor. Then it loops over those readings and inserts them into a map in which the key is the sensor name and the value is a vector of data for each sensor value.

---

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use std::collections::BTreeMap as Map;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Data {
    luminosity: Vec<Option<String>>,
    color: Vec<Option<String>>,
}

fn main() {
    let input = r##"[
                      {
                        "sensor": "left",
                        "luminosity": "50",
                        "color": "(255,0,0)"
                      },
                      {
                        "sensor": "left",
                        "color": "#0f0"
                      },
                      {
                        "sensor": "right",
                        "luminosity": "20"
                      },
                      {
                        "sensor": "right",
                        "luminosity": "40",
                        "color": "(255,0,0)"
                      },
                      {
                        "sensor": "left",
                        "luminosity": "30"
                      },
                      {
                        "sensor": "top",
                        "luminosity": "10"
                      },
                      {
                        "sensor": "right",
                        "color": "(0,0,0)"
                      }
                    ]"##;
    let m = read_sensor_data(input).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", m);
}

fn read_sensor_data(input: &str) -> Result<Map<String, Data>, Box<Error>> {
    // Private helper struct that matches the format of the raw JSON
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    struct RawReading {
        sensor: String,
        luminosity: Option<String>,
        color: Option<String>,
    }

    // Deserialize the raw data
    let raw_readings: Vec<RawReading> = serde_json::from_str(input)?;

    // Loop over raw data and insert each reading into the right sensor's struct
    let mut m = Map::new();
    for raw in raw_readings {
        // Look up this sensor's Data struct
        let sensor = m.entry(raw.sensor).or_insert_with(Data::default);

        // One push for every vector in the struct, even for missing observations
        sensor.luminosity.push(raw.luminosity);
        sensor.color.push(raw.color);
    }
    Ok(m)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can be *slightly* more efficient at the expense of more code. Deserializing the `Vec` is not necessary if you create your own `Visitor` implementation:

```
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fmt;
use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Visitor};

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Data {
    luminosity: Vec<Option<String>>,
    color: Vec<Option<String>>,
}

struct Wrapper(HashMap<String, Data>);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Wrapper {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_seq(WrapperVisitor)
    }
}

struct WrapperVisitor;

impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for WrapperVisitor {
    type Value = Wrapper;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("a sequence of measurement objects")
    }

    fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
    where
        A: serde::de::SeqAccess<'de>,
    {
        #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
        struct DataPoint {
            sensor: String,
            luminosity: Option<String>,
            color: Option<String>,
        }

        let mut all_data = HashMap::new();

        while let Some(data_point) = seq.next_element::<DataPoint>()? {
            let data = all_data
                .entry(data_point.sensor)
                .or_insert_with(Data::default);
            data.luminosity.push(data_point.luminosity);
            data.color.push(data_point.color);
        }

        Ok(Wrapper(all_data))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = r###"
[
    {
        "sensor": "left",
        "luminosity": "50",
        "color": "(255,0,0)"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "left",
        "color": "#0f0"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "right",
        "luminosity": "20"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "right",
        "luminosity": "40",
        "color": "(255,0,0)"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "left",
        "luminosity": "30"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "top",
        "luminosity": "10"
    },
    {
        "sensor": "right",
        "color": "(0,0,0)"
    }
]
"###;

    let data = serde_json::from_str::<Wrapper>(input).expect("Nope");
    let data = data.0;

    println!("{:#?}", data);
}
```

This produces the output:

```
{
    "left": Data {
        luminosity: [
            Some("50"),
            None,
            Some("30")
        ],
        color: [
            Some("(255,0,0)"),
            Some("#0f0"),
            None
        ]
    },
    "right": Data {
        luminosity: [
            Some("20"),
            Some("40"),
            None
        ],
        color: [
            None,
            Some("(255,0,0)"),
            Some("(0,0,0)")
        ]
    },
    "top": Data {
        luminosity: [
            Some("10")
        ],
        color: [
            None
        ]
    }
}
```